# Juggler must be played at the end of a trick or any time to trigger its event?

Tags: wizard

We’re playing the wizard jubilee edition and the rules seem to be unclear about this: the juggler has the effect that everyone in the game must pass a card to the left neighbor. Now the question is whether this event is triggered only when the juggler is played at the very end of the trick, so being the **last card** of the trick, **or** if the juggler can be played at **any moment** in the trick and still triggers its event?

Would appreciate if anybody has an answer to this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It triggers when the trick is finished, no matter which card it was. It doesn't have to be the last card played to the trick.

These [google-translate-based rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/217709/wizard-25th-edition-new-card-rules) are phrased ambiguously:

> When a trick is completed with the Juggler, each player
> simultaneously gives one of his hand cards face down to his left
> neighbor.

However, the [original German](https://www.amigo-spiele.de/content/download.php?group=rule&file=02101-DE-AmigoRule.pdf&title=02101-DE-AmigoRule.pdf) is not ambiguous. (Emphasis added)

> *Den Jongleur kannst du
> immer spielen, auch wenn du
> bedienen könntest. Er hat den
> Wert 7 1⁄2, ist also höher als
> eine 7 und niedriger als eine 8. Spielst du den Jongleur in
> einen Stich, sagst du deutlich
> an, welche Farbe (auch
> Trumpffarbe) die Karte annehmen soll. **Ist
> dieser Stich beendet, gibt jeder Lehrling
> gleichzeitig eine seiner Handkarten verdeckt
> an seinen linken Nachbarn.** Danach
> nimmt jeder seine neue Karte auf die Hand.
> Das Weitergeben der Karten entfällt, wenn
> der Stich mit dem Jongleur der letzte Stich
> einer Stichrunde war.*

Which translates to

> You can always play the Juggler play, even if you
> could follow suit. He has the
> Value 7 1⁄2, and so it is higher than
> a 7 and lower than an 8. When you play the Juggler to a trick, you state what suit (even
> Trump suit) the card is. **When the trick is finished, each apprentice simultaneously passes one of his hand cards facedown
> to his neighbor on his left.** Cards are not passed if
> the trick with the Juggler is the last trick
> of the round.

This [video explanation](https://youtu.be/Higriwiu0pQ?t=58) agrees (T=0:58)

Comment: An example of where failing to distinguish between the instrumental and genitive case can lead to ambiguity.